# Update file in subfolder of zip in linux / bash

Tags: linux, bash, zip, updates

I am trying update my zip but there is constant problem like `zip error: Nothing to do!` or wrong path with subfolders.

Input:
file to update /main/zip/folder_1/file1.xml

zip target: /main/zip_file1.zip  -> but this zip include subfolders like ../sub1/file1.xml  etc.

Expected result: update file1.xml in zip_file1.zip but in correct path like zip_file1.zip/sub1/file1.xml

how can I do it?

I was trying this:

```
zip -ur zip_file1.zip ./main/zip/folder_1/file1.xml

zip -ur zip_file1.zip '*/file1.xml' ./main/zip/folder_1/file1.xml

zip -ur zip_file1.zip '/sub1/file1.xml'./main/zip/folder_1/file1.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to make `main/zip/folder_1/file1.xml` be `sub1/file1.xml` in the zip archive, the paths must be **identical**.

A work-around is to recreate the trees and files that you want to update:

```sh
mkdir sub1
ln main/zip/folder_1/file1.xml sub1/
zip -rum zip_file1.zip sub1/
```

or

```
ln -s main/zip/folder_1/ sub1
zip -ru zip_file1.zip sub1/
rm -f sub1
```

Which one is the best depends on your context:

- use the first code for updating only a few select files of `main/zip/folder_1/`
- use the second code for updating all the files and directories in `main/zip/folder_1/`

Comment: yes, it's true - solution was creating the same folder tree and use this simple code `zip -u file_zip1.zip ./file_zip1/sub1/file1.xml`